# Saving a combo box value using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox

This question seems like pretty easy but when i save selected item from a combo box i get this result

```
{ user_name = Amanda, user_id = 1 }
```

here my code snippet for Loading The Combo Box

```
   //Task list ----> Load  users (Responsible person) into a combo box
    private void ComboResponsiblePerson()
    {
        //Get  list of users into the combo box
        //Task Tab
        BindingSource ResponsibleUser = new BindingSource();

        ResponsibleUser.DataSource = db.users.Select(_user => new
        {
            _user.user_name,_user.user_id
        }).ToList();

        if (ResponsibleUser != null)
        {

            cbResponsiblePerson.DataSource = ResponsibleUser;

            cbResponsiblePerson.DisplayMember = "user_name";
            //cbResponsiblePerson.d
            cbResponsiblePerson.ValueMember = "user_id";
        }

    }
```

And this is my code snippet to obtain the Selected item of Combo box

```
task.responsible_person = cbResponsiblePerson.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Task.Responsible_person is a string attribute.

Here i only want to get the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `cbResponsiblePerson.SelectedItem` is one of the anonymous objects returned by your query.  Executing `ToString()` on it prints the object.  If you want the name you might want to define the anonymous type as a real type.

If you are in WinForms you can do the following:

```
cbResponsiblePerson.GetItemText(cbResponsiblePerson.SelectedItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you check `ResponsibleUser` with`null` while you initiated it befor!.

To get `user_name` :

```
cbResponsiblePerson.Text
```

And to get `user_id` :

```
cbResponsiblePerson.SelectedValue
```

Your DataSource has Ananymouse Type members and you can use Reflection to getting values:

```
 var selectedItem = cbResponsiblePerson.SelectedItem;
 var idp = selectedItem.GetProperty("user_id");
 var namep = selectedItem.GetProperty("user_name");
 var user_id  = idp.GetValue(selectedItem);
 var user_name = namep.GetValue(selectedItem);
```